# How to store certificates in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, certificate

Below is the collection, where each document suppose to store certificate and public key in document:

```
[
   {
      "name" : "cluster-1-in-gcp",
      "kubernetes-version": "1.16",
      "server": "https://192.168.10.190:6443",
      "user": "kubernetes-admin-1",
      "client-certificate": "sadfhdsjfkhsdjfklhsdjfkassdfsd",
      "client-key": "sahgjkshfgjkdf"      
   },
   {
      "name" : "cluster-1-in-aws",
      "kubernetes-version": "1.17",
      "server": "https://192.168.11.191:6443",
      "user": "kubernetes-admin-2",
      "client-certificate": "ssssshdsjfkhsdjfklhsdjfkassdfsd",
      "client-key": "pppppsahgjkshfgjkdf"
   },
   {
      "name" : "cluster-1-in-aks",
      "kubernetes-version": "1.18",
      "server": "https://192.168.11.192:6443",
      "user": "kubernetes-admin-3",
      "client-certificate": "oooossssshdsjfkhsdjfklhsdjfkassdfsd",
      "client-key": "tttttpppppsahgjkshfgjkdf"      
   },
]
```

---

What should be the schema of document?

Answer (score 1):

What are the format of the certificate and private keys?

If they are PEM, then store them as strings.

If they are DER, then store them as binary data (binData).

Comment: Why DER format should be stored as binData?

Comment: @overexchange - because DER is a binary format. You could base64 encode DER and then store it as a string.